# despite running a blocking method in run_in_executor, I get "Executing Task pending" notifications

Tags: python, multithreading, python-asyncio

I run a blocking method in loop.run_in_executor as provided in many examples but get nevertheless such notifications when the code is executing

```
Executing <Task pending name='Task-11' coro=<WebSocketCommonProtocol.keepalive_ping() running at /home/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/websockets/protocol.py:1134> wait_for=<Future pending cb=[<TaskWakeupMethWrapper object at 0x7fdf6d9f0250>()] created at /home/anaconda3/envs/map/lib/python3.8/asyncio/tasks.py:466> created at /home/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/websockets/protocol.py:334> took 0.125 seconds
```

here is the code snippet:

```
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
executor = ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=4)
await loop.run_in_executor(executor, reader.create_dataset)
```

here are the logger settings

```
os.environ['PYTHONASYNCIODEBUG'] = '1'
logger = logging.getLogger("api")
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
logging.getLogger("asyncio").setLevel(logging.WARNING)
```

Comment: It seems like an issue in the [`keepalive_ping`](https://github.com/aaugustin/websockets/blob/0bfa9f2ea86dbc12f24e4a2756cb339efafe76d8/src/websockets/legacy/protocol.py#L1085) method from websockets. But it's quite short and there doesn't appear anything suspicious there. Do you perhaps have debug logging turned on, and have configured a logger that might be slow?

Comment: @user4815162342 I updated my post with logger settings. That might be indeed the keeplive_ping from websockets, since I have a cycle for them. But I didn't get these notifications before and reader.create_dataset method is executed in another thread. I am confused why I get it suddenly. And the number of this notification is high, it seems to be every 10 seconds.

Comment: I don't think it has anything to do with `create_dataset`, but who knows. Try to disable debug logging and see if the problem persists. Where do your logs go to, is it possible that they end up in a pipe or somewhere that would cause the log.debug call to take a while to execute?